# pydantic: How to ignore invalid values when creating model instance

Tags: python, validation, pydantic, typing

Given a sample model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Foo(BaseModel):
     age: Optional[int]
     name: Optional[str]
```

I would like my model to be able to digest-but-ignore invalid values to receive an instance in any case. E.g.:

```
Foo(age="I", name="Jim")
```

should instead of raising a `ValidationError` automatically discard the value for the `age` field and results in

```
Foo(age=None, name='Jim')
```

I could manually loop over the `ValidationErrors` and drop the corresponding data or loop over the values and use `validate_assignment`, but I was thinking I am missing something built-in.

Comment: Please always specify the relevant versions in your questions. Pydantic for instance just had a new major release and the answers may differ significantly depending on whether you are dealing with v1 or v2. Also stating your Python version should just be mandatory IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pre-validator to convert non-int values to `None`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import Optional

class Foo(BaseModel):
     age: Optional[int]
     name: Optional[str]

     @validator('age', pre=True)
     def validate_age(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, int):
            v = None
        return v
```

With the above code:

```
>>> Foo(age='I', name='alice')
Foo(age=None, name='alice')
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but if you're using a current version of Python you can replace your use of `Optional`. The following code is equivalent:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Foo(BaseModel):
     age: int|None
     name: str|None

     @validator('age', pre=True)
     def validate_age(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, int):
            v = None
        return v
```

### Update

You can validate **all** fields using a `root_validator` (pydantic 1.x) or a `model_validator` (pydantic 2.x). For pydantic 2.x, that might look like:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    age: int | None
    name: str | None

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def validate_all(cls, v):
        for name, spec in cls.model_fields.items():
            if not isinstance(v[name], spec.annotation):
                v[name] = None

        return v
```

Hopefully the above code is relatively obvious: we're iterating over the field definitions, checking if a given value in `v` matches the type annotation for the field, and if not, replacing the value with `None`.

Comment: Thank you @larsks. My example model was intentionally kept very simple, while my real world model has more complex input requirements defined in the Field(...). To repeat that in a validator method doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: See my update, but also note that you'll get better answers if you ensure the example in your question is representative of the real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Note: That [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) check will fail on Python `<3.10`! This is particularly important in this context because the `FieldInfo.annotation` attribute is very likely (and in this example _definitely_) going to hold a [union type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#union-type). And even on Python `>=3.10` it will fail as soon as you introduce parameterized generics like `list[str]`. The approach itself via a `model_validator` is great, but you have to be very careful with how you check the type coherence there.

Answer (score 1):

## Pydantic `2.x`

This is the prime use case for the [`WrapValidator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#wrap-validators) metadata class.

You can define a function to be called *around* the actual validator. That way you can *try* to apply the actual validator and upon failure return `None` instead.

#### On a per-field basis

For your example `age` field, you would do it like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, WrapValidator


def invalid_to_none(v: Any, handler: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Any:
    try:
        return handler(v)
    except ValidationError:
        return None


class Foo(BaseModel):
    age: Annotated[int | None, WrapValidator(invalid_to_none)]
    name: str | None
```

Demo:

```py
instance = Foo(age="invalid", name="Jim")
print(instance.model_dump())  # {'age': None, 'name': 'Jim'}
```

The problem of course is that it is applied on a per-field basis.

#### Applying to *all* model fields

To avoid repeating the [`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) type definition for every single field (assuming you want it to apply to all fields), we need to get a bit creative.

One option is to hook into class construction via [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) and patch every field annotation with the same `WrapValidator`. Here is a somewhat crude example of a custom base model that you could use:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Annotated, Any, get_args, get_origin

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, WrapValidator


def invalid_to_none(v: Any, handler: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Any:
    try:
        return handler(v)
    except ValidationError:
        return None


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        for name, annotation in cls.__annotations__.items():
            if name.startswith("_"):  # exclude protected/private attributes
                continue
            validator = WrapValidator(invalid_to_none)
            if get_origin(annotation) is Annotated:
                cls.__annotations__[name] = Annotated[
                    *get_args(annotation),
                    validator,
                ]
            else:
                cls.__annotations__[name] = Annotated[annotation, validator]
```

Note that I am consciously using [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48) directly rather than calling [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) here because it would attempt to resolve forward references and I want to interfere as little as possible with the Pydantic model construction algorithm.

I am simply ignoring every name in the class namespace that starts with an underscore because those are typically reserved. I am also taking care to re-create already existing `Annotated` type hints and append the `WrapValidator` to the end of any metadata already present.

Demo:

```py
...

class Foo(CustomBaseModel):
    age: int | None
    name: str | None
    bar: Annotated[float | None, "other metadata"]


instance = Foo(age="invalid", name="Jim", bar=object())
print(instance.model_dump())  # {'age': None, 'name': 'Jim', 'bar': None}
```

As you can see, both the `age` and the `bar` fields were assigned `None` and no `ValidationError` was actually raised.

I should emphasize that this method of patching the field annotations is just an example to illustrate the overall approach. I am not claiming that I thought of every possible pitfall. Make sure to test it with your specific use cases.

---

## Pydantic `1.x`

The [solution proposed by @larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670675/19770795) with a [`root_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#root-validators) is very reasonable in principle. You just need to be careful with the type checks because the field annotations can be very tricky.

One fool-proof but **inefficient** approach is to just call `ModelField.validate` for all fields inside the custom root validator and see if it returns errors. If it does, assign `None` and move on.

Here is a working example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def invalid_to_none(cls, values: dict[str, object]) -> dict[str, object]:
        validated_values: dict[str, object] = {}
        for name, value in values.items():
            field = cls.__fields__.get(name)
            if field is None:  # must be extra data
                continue
            validated_value, errors = field.validate(
                value,
                validated_values,
                loc="__root__",
                cls=cls,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
            )
            validated_values[name] = validated_value
            if errors:
                values[name] = None
        return values


class Foo(CustomBaseModel):
    age: int | None
    name: str | None


instance = Foo(age="invalid", name="Jim", extra=object())
print(instance.dict())  # {'age': None, 'name': 'Jim'}
```

As you can see, it works as expected.

The reason this is inefficient though is that it will effectively call *all* validators for all fields **twice** -- once in that custom root validator and once in the "regular" validation cycle.

It is still idempotent because we don't actually *do anything* with the pre-validated values. We discard them and just return the non-validated values from the root validator. But still, this can be a deal-breaker, if you have many custom validation functions and performance is critical.